# Decode html entities using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to decode entities using BeautifulSoup but with no luck.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

decoded = BeautifulSoup("&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;",convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

print decoded
```

The output is not decoded at all. I found a lot of answers here that use this method.
Am I a doing something wrong?

I would like to use BeautifulSoup for this so please don't bother telling me that the standard library has a method to decode entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [`print decoded.contents`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Entity%20Conversion):

```
>>> print decoded
&lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;
>>> print decoded.contents
[u'<p> </p>']
```