# Compare two texts

Tags: python, text, unicode, elgg, unicode-normalization

In order to validate a migration tool, I want to compare two texts, one of the source A the other from the target tool B. To populate B, I'm using a reste API JSON-Based. B applies some "transformations" on the text that i don't know exactly what.

Here is the snippet of my code that i'm using:

```
  bkclient = Client()
  for mapping in BkMapping.select(): #get all objects
    entity = Elgg_Entities.get(Elgg_Entities.guid == mapping.elgg_id)
    if entity.subtype == 5:#postopic
      pass
    else:
      elgg_desc = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", entity.entity.description)
      bk_content = unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", bkclient.get_post(mapping.bkid).get("data").get('content'))

      if resume(bk_content) == resume(elgg_desc):
        pass
      else:
        print('bk content')
        print(bk_content)
        print("elgg content")
        print(elgg_desc)
        input('continue...')
```

As result:

```
#### bk content (B) ######
<p>Bonjour à tous,</p>
<p>Je souhaite récolter des informations sur les actions menées en faveur des Seniors au sein du Groupe.</p>
<p>Si vous menez ou avez mené des actions en faveur des seniors et de leur insertion, pourriez-vous m’en faire part. Si je peux avoir des retours d’ici demain matin, ce serait super ! Merci d’avance de vos retours.</p>
######### elgg content (A) #########
<p>Bonjour &agrave; tous,</p>

<p>Je souhaite r&eacute;colter des informations sur les actions men&eacute;es en faveur des Seniors au sein du Groupe.</p>

<p>Si vous menez ou avez men&eacute; des actions en faveur des seniors et de leur insertion, pourriez-vous m&rsquo;en faire part. Si je peux avoir des retours d&rsquo;ici demain matin, ce serait super&nbsp;! Merci d&rsquo;avance de vos retours.</p>
```

So, I looking for a tool to make a hash of those texts which deals with accents <=>html entities, spaces, etc.

Comment: I believe the default hashing tool should work, you'll just need to specify the character set in the python file so the program knows you're using unicode.

Comment: Using http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hash, returns different values, I'm on Python3...

Comment: It seems you're looking for a [diff tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff)

Comment: could be very tricky, to use an external tool... My first aims was to automize the validation. So adding some layer to the script, it will make me to test the test script. 
I would like a light method, I wondered if count all 'a' or an other pattern could achieve the goal ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out how to do, [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10088318/decode-html-entities-using-beautifulsoup) can decode html entities :

```
def remove_accents(input_str):
    nkfd_form = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', input_str)
    only_ascii = nkfd_form.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    return only_ascii

def normalize(text):
  text = re.sub(r'\s+', '', str(BeautifulSoup(text)), flags = re.MULTILINE)
  return str(remove_accents(text))

def compare_text(s1, s2):
  s1 = normalize(s1.lower())
  s2 = normalize(s2.lower())
  l1 = len(s1)
  l2 = len(s2)
  if l1 == l2:
    return  s1 == s2
  return False

t1="""      
<p>Bonjour à tous,</p>
<p>Je souhaite récolter des informations sur les actions menées en faveur des Seniors au sein du Groupe.</p>
<p>Si vous menez ou avez mené des actions en faveur des seniors et de leur insertion, pourriez-vous m’en faire part. Si je peux avoir des retours d’ici demain matin, ce serait super ! Merci d’avance de vos retours.</p>
"""
t2="""
<p>Bonjour &agrave; tous,</p>

<p>Je souhaite r&eacute;colter des informations sur les actions men&eacute;es en faveur des Seniors au sein du Groupe.</p>

<p>Si vous menez ou avez men&eacute; des actions en faveur des seniors et de leur insertion, pourriez-vous m&rsquo;en faire part. Si je peux avoir des retours d&rsquo;ici demain matin, ce serait super&nbsp;! Merci d&rsquo;avance de vos retours.</p>  
"""

print(compare_text(t1, t2))
True
```